# How to Activate Breakpoints in a Dependent Project (a framework) in XCode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, debugging

I have an Xcode project that has an other project as a dependent project. My main Xcode project links agains a framework in that dependent project.

Now I want to track down something in my framework. How can I set break points in that dependent project so that when I'm starting my main Xcode project they stop in the dependent project? Sometimes, I'm able to get into a some parts of the framework with just stepping in but the breakpoints in the dependent project aren't working.

Any suggestions how I can make these breakpoints in a dependent Xcode project work?

Comment: Have the dependant project open, make sure it is a debug build. Make sure the framework you have linked against is the debug build. ie, if there is more than one copy of the framework on your disk, depending on how your search paths are set you could be linking against a different build. Are you on ppc or 386?

Comment: @mustISignUp -- you should make this comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 3.2.2 has a known bug with debugging frameworks.  Fall back to 3.2.1 until a newer version is released.

Comment: That explains a lot! Because I had in mind that it once worked. Do you know if it's fixed in Xcode 3.2.3?

Comment: I think it is fixed in 3.2.3, but a new bug (involving dwarf with dSym generation) prevents me from using 3.2.3.

Comment: The 3.2.3 release notes say "A case where breakpoints in a shared library would not be hit has been fixed. 7212899"

Comment: I tried to not upgrade because the 3.2.3 has some problems with iPhone and Mac targets in the same Xcode project. 
Let's hope Xcode 4 fixes all problems.